# How to use python script to generate iso-surface and export scene to *.vrml file in Paraview?

Tags: python, contour, paraview

The work flow is like this, I import the data in Paraview. Then get isosurface contour using one value then export scene to *.vrml format, then use another value to get the isosurface then export it so on so forth. I'm wondering how to write python script to reduce the work load since there are many values that I need to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find the python equivalent for the gui commands is to use the trace option from the Tools menu. 
You can also save paraview state as a python script (look in the option "save as .py" instead of pvsm).

I have not experience with vrml format, but you can have a look at some snippets in http://www.paraview.org/pipermail/paraview/2013-January/027270.html